# Using define in a c header file

Tags: c, constants, header-files

I am just starting to learn C so hopefully this isn't a dumb question.  The problem I am having is regarding header files and using #define for constants.  I have read that I should use the following to prevent my header from being compiled more than once.

```
#ifndef NAME_OF_FILE
#define NAME_OF_FILE
.
. //my header file content
.
#endif
```

I want to add a constant, and I believe I would also use a #define such as,

```
#ifndef NAME_OF_FILE
#define NAME_OF_FILE

#define NUM_CONST 5 //the constant I want in my header file
.
.
.
#endif
```

How does C know that #define NAME_OF_FILE is referring to the .h file while #define NUM_CONST 5 is just a constant?  Is it because of the value at the end of NUM_CONST? Or do I have this all completely wrong?

Comment: The compiler does _not_ know that `NAME_OF_FILE` is special. It is only special by _convention_. It is the "lock" for the file (i.e.) the file could be `#include`ed several times, but the lock prevents the contents between the lock construct and the corresponding `#endif` from being read by the compiler more than once. It is the C preprocessor that does this actually. If you follow the logic step-by-step, the 1st time, the `#ifndef` is true, so the [1st] `#define` and the remainder is included. On the 2nd try, the `#ifndef` is false and skips to the `#endif` at the bottom

Answer (score 4):

There is no essential difference between the two defines. `#define NAME_OF_FILE` and `#define NUM_CONST 5` are the same sort of thing.  They define a plaintext replacement of tokens (in the first case, the replacement is nothing).

For example you could put subsequent code:

```
printf("%d\n", NAME_OF_FILE NUM_CONST NAME_OF_FILE);
```

and after the above substitutions the code would turn in to:

```
printf("%d\n", 5);
```

which is correct. There is no "magic". The compilation step that performs these substitutions is usually known as "preprocessing".

`NAME_OF_FILE` does not refer to the `.h` file, per se, but the use of the `ifndef` directive achieves the goal of not compiling the same code twice.

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't. `NAME_OF_FILE` could be anything. You could have

```
#ifndef PRETTY_PINK_PRINCESS
#define PRETTY_PINK_PRINCESS
/* definitions */
#endif
```

And it would work just as well. Using `NAME_OF_FILE` is just a convention because it makes it likely that it's unique.

Answer (score 3):

`#define IDENTIFIER` defines the identifier for the sakes of `#ifdef`, but what it is being defined *to* is the empty string.

So,

```
#define NAME_OF_FILE

int main()
{
    int x = NAME_OF_FILE;
}
```

would resolve to

```
int main()
{
    int x = ;
}
```

So there is no "knowing" involved, just a defined-but-empty.

(That is why some style guides out there recommend `#define NAME_OF_FILE NAME_OF_FILE`, so that if `NAME_OF_FILE` *happens* to be used in the source, it is replaced-with-self by the preprocessor.)

Comment: A great idea about `#define NAME_OF_FILE NAME_OF_FILE`! I have never heard about this; do you have any link to where it's mentioned?

Comment: @anatolyg: It has been a *loooong* time (try 15 years or so) since I bothered with style guides. The important things become second nature, the merely stylistic ones you cover with tools like Astyle. It was around, and I picked it up as "it can't hurt, so why not'. No idea where I got it from.

Answer (score 0):

For the compiler both these statement are the same type a macro

```
#define NAME_OF_FILE

#define NUM_CONST 5
```

That this construct

```
#ifndef NAME_OF_FILE
#define NAME_OF_FILE
.
. //my header file content
.
#endif
```

is doing, is that the header is processed for the first time, the marco "NAME_OF_FILE" is n ot defined, hence it get defined and the whole header file content processed. The second time the compiler comes around this, because the header was included in project more than once, is that the marco is defined now and the header file doesn't get processed again.
Again, the "c-code" is not aware, that the marco __TEST_H for example has its because the header file's name is 'test.h'. What you are reffering to is probably, that your IDE auto-generated the marco then you created the header file and that the IDE called the marco after the file for the user's convenience. Like a another one here allready said, that you can rename the marco (rename it in the whole project I mean by that) and the code would compile and generally behave exactly like before.